# fundamental frequency using cepstrum

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency

I need to find the fundamental frequency of the bearing faults. I am plotting the cepstrum with the frequency. Will the results be same as the plot with quefrequncy or do I need to plot in time domain?

plot(freq_s(2:250),cceps(abs(Signal_fft_hilbert_Mean(i, 2:250))),C{z})

Answer (score 0):

There is a mathworks article about this [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/ug/estimating-fundamental-frequency-with-the-complex-cepstrum.html).

they plot the cepstrum for timeframes, then identify the peak in the cepstrum and find the frequency corresponding to the peak.

Comment: but if I am directly plotting frequency is it wrong?

Comment: i am not quite sure what you mean with "directly plotting the frequency". the cepstrum is like the frequency of the frequency, so the axis for it is `1/hz`, so you could call that a time...